# How to interpret this Haskell code that type checks?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Studying the book [Haskell Programming from First Principles](http://www.haskellbook.com/), I've come across the following exercise in Chapter 6, "Typeclasses":

```
-- Hint: use some arithmetic operation to
-- combine values of type 'b'. Pick one.
arith :: Num b => (a -> b) -> Integer -> a -> b
arith = ???
```

I have come up with the following solution, and I call it a 'solution' because it compiles:

```
arith f _ x = f x
```

But I'm somewhat confused how to 'interpret' what I've just written above. My 'reading' of the type signature of `arith` is something like the following:

> `arith` takes one function, one `Integer`, a parameter of type `a`,
>   and returns a result that is of type `b`; moreover, the function that
>   `arith` takes as the first parameter is a function that takes a
>   parameter of type `a` and returns a value of type `b`, and that value
>   has to be of type `b` whose typeclass is (or 'constrained') by `Num`.

and after that, I came up with the 'solution' above but I haven't used "some arithmetic operation to combine values of type 'b'". Somehow I think either the 'hint' is misleading, or it is perfectly fine, and I'm missing something, if that's the case, then what am I missing?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution - it is but one of many possibles solutions to that type signature

Comment: Well, it is very certainly not _the intended solution_. Not only do you not use some arithmetic operation, you just completely ignore the integer argument. What the intended solution could actually be I'm less than sure myself; there really are plenty of completely different possible approaches.

Comment: The book says "you’re trying to fill in terms (code) which’ll fit the type. The idea with these exercises is that you’ll derive the implementation from the type information. You’ll probably need to use stuff from Prelude." So my understanding is that the type signature must strongly constrain my solution and guide me towards an implementation, it's just that I'm a little stuck as to what other concrete implementation I can come up with :(

Comment: Indeed it's often possible to derive an implementation from type information, but this is not really a good example – `Num` is just a way too vague, and with an `Integer` you can do _anything_. I really think they should reconsider that exercise.

Comment: As a specific example, you could apply `(+)` to both the `Integer` argument and `f x`, since both values have types that are instances of `Num`. There isn't a *right* answer, just lots and lots of *valid* answers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not sure I entirely agree that `Num` is too vague. It's rather 'strong' in a way, namely that what you can do with `b` just being `Num` is very limited. `Num` has a `fromInteger`, which connects the `Integer` parameter to `b`, and then there's three binary operations, `+, -, *` that can then be used.

Comment: Emre Here is a clue. Call the function "rescale" and think of the first argument f as somehow eg measuring an "a"

Comment: @EmreSevinç You may enjoy making the exercise harder by imposing an extra restriction on yourself: use all the arguments on the right-hand side of the equals sign. (Your current solution ignores the second argument. There are other solutions that ignore other arguments -- a followup exercise might be to try to find some of these as well.) Overall I think this particular exercise is too vague to be a good one -- exactly because of the kind of confusion you're feeling right now. It's not you; it's the book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the *intended solution* is:

```
arith f i a = f a + fromInteger i
```

Or one with `+` replaced by `-` or `*`.

**To recap the requirements:** In this exercise you have to implement a function that:

1. Matches type signature `arith :: Num b => (a -> b) -> Integer -> a -> b`.
2. Uses arithmetic operation to combine values of type `b`.

You are given three values of types `(a -> b)`, `Integer` and `a`. As a first step you need to convert them to two values of type `b`. You can get first one by applying `(a -> b)` to `a`. Then you are left with value of type `Integer`. When you [notice](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) that instances of typeclass `Num` support function `fromInteger :: Integer -> a` (where type `a` is type `b` in context of function we are defining), it becomes clear that you can obtain second value of type `b` by applying `fromInteger` to your `Integer` value. As a second step you combine two values of type `b` using one of arithmetic operations defined in `Num` typeclass.

Comment: Thank you and all the other commentators above for shedding light that made my understanding stronger. PS: I've also dabbled with `fromInteger` for sometime while trying to come up with a solution, but somehow was still confused, having spent even more time together with all the comments above was really helpful!